# C# get relative path of resources folder

Tags: c#, directory, path, resources

I want to acess a .txt file, which I stored in the resources folder of my project, there where all the imported pictures are stored as well.
I want to use something like a relative path, since every user would have safed his programm somewehere else on his Pc, but there is always the resources folder at the same place, compared to the programm folder.

I tried to used this: `displayText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Resources\\startmessages.txt");` but this isn't working.
I get this error message: **System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:**, it lists the unrelative path to the .txt there as well, so I don't get, why it cant read it.

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: So the the `Resources` folder is located at the same location where the application is running? Did you confirm that the folder exists?

Comment: It always exists automatically, when you create your project. I should have specified, that I am creating a 'windows forms app'. The folder is the one, were you import your project resources like background pictures, for buttons, forms, pictureboxes and so on

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/858488/In-Csharp-Windows-Forms-Application-how-to-have-a

Comment: You don't import resources in that Folder. `Resources` is used by Visual Studio, it's not meant for your application to access. Event though you *can* add files there (which will create *confusion* between what's used as Embedded Resource and what's there for other reasons), that folder won't be available when you deploy. If you want to organize your files in directories in your Project, add folders to Solution Explorer and define the `Build Action` of the files these folders contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @ChetanRanpariya is trying to tell you is, that your programm is **built** in another folder than your folder `Resources` is sitting to. So you  have explictly tell your file `Resources\startmessages.txt` to copy itself on build process, so it get copied to said another folder. Assuming that you are using Visual Studio, you have to right click on your file and set `Copy To Output Directory` to `true`. Its relative folder path (`Resources\`) will be taken over. You find your build folder somewhere in your `bin` folder depending on configuration and framework. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Current Path where your executable is**

```
Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).FullName
```

**Path to Solution**

If you are using Visual Studio and need to access the folders in the solution directory, you can use `.Parent` method,

```
Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName
```

**Use of Path.Combine**

and once you have the location of your Resource folder, use Path.Combine to get the location to read files / content etc

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "Resources\\startMessages.txt")
```